# How to use PHP to read excel file and update PDO database with new values?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, pdo, spreadsheet

I have been asked to come up with pseudo code using PHP to read an excel file, loop through the rows and update the database with the new values from the file. I have never used or written PHP before. I am unfamiliar with just about all of it.

Any advice, help, tips, etc would be useful. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

How can I use PHP to read excel file and update PDO database with new values? Is there a better way?

Here is the structure of the excel file:

[image]

Here is so code that I have written so far...

```
$match_table = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("spreadsheets/mySpreadsheet");
$count = $match_table->rowcount();

//open connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  
  for ($i = 2; $i <= $count; $i++) 
    {​​​​​​​                       
        $vendor_nbr = trim($match_table->val($i, 1));
        $lead_time = trim($match_table->val($i, 2));

        $data = [
          'vndrNumber' => $vendor_nbr,
          'leadTime' => $lead_time,
        ];

      $sql = "UPDATE vendor SET vndr_std_lt=leadtime WHERE vndr_cd=vndrNumber";
      $stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute($data);
    }​​​​​​​
  }
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: No Connection";
}
$conn = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below code for database update... the code above to loop through excel spreadsheet is accurate.

```
$sql = "UPDATE vendor SET vndr_std_lt=leadtime WHERE vndr_cd=vndrNumber";

$result = odbc_Exec($conn, $sql);
```